# API for checking blacklisted ip addresses?

Tags: api, security, ip, blacklist

I would like to check a list of ip addresses and see if they are blacklisted (which would make me block them on my server).

Which recommended websites offer such a service?

Comment: Please see this URL http://auz.github.io/HP_BlackList/

Comment: I don't know if you want to do manual blocking or not. For manual blocking, you can try: http://mail-blacklist-monitor.online-domain-tools.com/ and otherwise http://mail-blacklist-checker.online-domain-tools.com/ with API http://docs.online-domain-tools.com/ODT%20-%20API%20v1.1.1.pdf

Answer (score 6):

We have created a bash script for checking a domain or an IP adress.
It is quite easy to use and available on GitHub.

https://github.com/IntellexApps/blcheck

Comment: It'll be good to know which blacklists, RBLs, or malware lists are covered by your tool. Is Google Safebrowsing list included, or SURBL, or SpamCop? Thank you.

Comment: @PKHunter The list of all RBLs are included in the script itself in CONF_BLACKLISTS. I'm kinda lazy to update the list and relynig on the community to send updates :)

Comment: ive been fishing around for a free api to do this, but you have it soundly covered with this script! thank you!

Comment: [Blacklist Checker API](https://blacklistchecker.com) is also a good option which covers these blacklists you mentioned and also handles errors from each blacklist which comes up quite often.

Answer (score 4):

Check out-

https://www.projecthoneypot.org/ and

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/ (this one is provided by Google and is used by Chrome to check for malicious web hosts)

Answer (score 2):

To check list of IP addresses are blacklisted or not, use "whoisthisip's [blacklist checker tool](http://whoisthisip.com/ipblock/).

Comment: Looks like the sorbs.net result is always wrong for every domain entered and at least one of the checks is 404. Probably hasn't been maintained.

Answer (score 1):

See -

http://myip.ms/browse/blacklist/Blacklist_IP_Blacklist_IP_Addresses_Live_Database_Real-time

They have fresh spam bot/scam ip database (updated daily)

Comment: Looks too strict, IMO. For example, blocked Majestic and that's a good bot you want crawling your website https://majestic.com/ Full disclosure: I have no affiliation with Majestic.

Answer (score 0):

There are many services found on the net . I can say MxtoolBox is an option for you .

If you are looking for a standalone application , you can depend on IpBlacklist Checker .
http://www.webtoolsin.com/products-1-ip-blacklist-checker.html